# Get HTML string from asp.net MVC ActionResult in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am implementing an offline html to pdf printing function.  I want to get the html that would be returned by a view and save it to a file on the server side.

```
    public JsonResult MyReportOfflinePrint(MyParameters p)
    {
        ActionResult res = MyReportPrintMethod(p);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myreport.html")) {
            sw.Write(res.GetTheHtmlString???) 
        }
         return Json("it worked");
```

I could use http as a web service and call self, but since this view is already available in the same controller that seems like a waste.

I have seen questions about calling a different controller, and returning a raw string as a view, but I want to capture the html string produced by razor engine.

Comment: So what did your search for "ASP.NET MVC render view to string" yield? Have you found [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this.  I was missing the magic word Render.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.